# submit Form and String using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to submit both a Form and a String using Ajax 
I tried this but didn't work, As I can't get `$_POST['foo'])` in PHP page :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#togreenform').submit(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST', 
      url: 'operations.php?r=togreen', 
      data: { $(this).serialize(), 
        'foo': 'bar'}, 
      success: function(msg) { 
        alert(JSON.parse(msg)); 
      }, 
      error: function() { 
        //alert('failure'); 
      } 
    }) 
    return false; // prevent form from submitting 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: you'll need to be a lot more specific than "didn't work". What was the expected behaviour, and what actual behaviour did you observe? Did you see any error messages or other output in your client side app, or in the browser console, or in the server-side code? It would also be helpful if you post the server-side code that processes this call

Comment: _"but didn't work"_: what did not work? what errors you get?

Comment: Sorry, I will edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data property should look like this :

```
data : {
    foo: 'bar',
    otherprop: 'foo'
};
```

or

```
data : $(this).serialize()+"&foo=bar"
```

The serialize function create a string creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation.

Your code is producing an invalid object since you don't provide a value with your first key (which is the text string).

Answer (score 1):

This is an invalid object:

```
{
  $(this).serialize(),
  'foo': 'bar'
}
```

The first property wasn't given a name.  You can give it one:

```
{
  'form': $(this).serialize(),
  'foo': 'bar'
}
```